# Connect links inside an dijit.dialog

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

i have some trouble to connect an link inside an dijit.dialog.

Iam calling an "other" html file inside the Dialog (dialog.href="xxx.html") inside this file iam trying to connect some links by id, to fire an alert box. But nothing happens ? Possible that this isnt possible ??

Thats the part from my xxx.html file..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.addOnLoad(function( ) {
        dojo.connect(dojo.byId('testLink'), 'onClick', alert('xx'));
    }); </script>


<a href='#' id="testLink">TEST</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dialog is extended from ContentPane so it supports all the same parameters (href, etc.)](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dijit.Dialog).  With that said, when a page is included via the href property any `<script`> tags are not evaluated they are just added to the DOM.  This leaves you with two choices:

1. refactor xxx.html, so the script can be run by the dialog's onLoad handler
2. embed the event handlers into the html tags; i.e. `<input type="button" onClick="alert('xx');" /`>

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [dojox.layout.ContentPane](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/layout/ContentPane).  It'll parse <script> tags.  It's in dojox though so it's liable to change in future version.  And another downside is that this would require creating your own Dialog class that's a subclass of dojox.layout.ContentPane.

There's also an article on dojocampus [about executing javascript in content panes](http://dojocampus.org/content/2008/07/30/executing-javascript-inside-content-panes/) which talks a little bit about using dojox.layout.ContentPane to roll  your own Dialog widgets.